# JavaScript, Execute function after function

Tags: javascript, methods, callback

```
mainFunc(){
 firstFunc();
 SecondFunc();
 Playball();
}


function Playball () {

var paper = new Raphael(0, 0, 800, 500);
var backGround = paper.rect(0, 0, 800, 500);

var ball = paper.circle(400, 0, 30);
ball.attr({fill: "blue"});

function step1() {
    ball.animate({cx: 400, cy: 600}, 2500);
}

step1();
};
```

This is what I've written so far, I have more functions that need to be executed consecutively. I'm aware that I can use a simple callback function but I can't get it work, Step2 never executes. Below is what I've tried. Also is there a better method that I can use in this scenario given that I have multiple functions. I'm unable to use the SetTimeout since my main function is triggered on a click event.

```
function Playball (callback) {

var paper = new Raphael(0, 0, 800, 500);
var backGround = paper.rect(0, 0, 800, 500);

var ball = paper.circle(400, 0, 30);
ball.attr({fill: "blue"});

function step1() {
    ball.animate({cx: 400, cy: 600}, 2500);
}

step1();
return true;
};

Playball(step2());
```

Comment: `Playball(); step2()` should work better for you. I don't see any reasons to use a callback here?

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: I did try this but step2 does not execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you'd like step2 to start after the animation of step1,so does this work?

```
function Playball (callback) {

  var paper = new Raphael(0, 0, 800, 500);
  var backGround = paper.rect(0, 0, 800, 500);

  var ball = paper.circle(400, 0, 30);
  ball.attr({fill: "blue"});
  //http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Element.animate
  function step1() {
    ball.animate(
      {cx: 400, cy: 600}//params
      , 2500            //number of milliseconds for animation to run
      ,undefined        //easing type
      ,callback         //callback function. Will be called at the end of animation
    );
  }

  step1();
  return true;
};

Playball(step2);
```

An example fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HkNgT/236/).